# Get argc is zero and argv is null when debuging codes in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have encounted a very strange problem today. I Created four configurations for my project, they are

```
X86|Debug
X86|Release
X64|Debug
X64|Release
```

Only in `X64|Release`, I always got main function's two parameters that `argc==0` and `argv==NULL` when start debuging my code through `F10/F11`. Since in the other 3 configurations the parameters are OK! I've tried to create new project/solution several times but the problem still exists.

My IDE is visual studio 2012 in Win7/x64, Please help me to find the problem, Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this program through the debugger?

Comment: Yes, I press F10 to start debuging my program. only in X64|Release, the parameters are 0. very strange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debugger is lying to you.

In Release builds, Visual Studio often throws away too much information about the optimizations applied to the code, so the variable watch windows often print garbage values. An easy way to ease this situation a bit is using [the `/d2Zi+` compile flag](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2011/10/12/debugging-optimized-code-in-visual-studio-11/). Just add it as an additional build option (Project Properties->C++->Command Line->Additional Options) and you should see the correct values again.

Comment: Many thanks! I found the problem! When I printf out the parameters, they are ok!

Comment: @user2841150 If you find an answer useful, please consider upvoting it, or even mark it as an accepted answer to your question.